# weird Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

I am trying to implement an array using 2 stacks named stack and buffer.
Initially the stack is filled with random values, the MyArrayI interface contains 2 functions: getItemAt(int index) and setItemAt(int index, int item). and they are successfully implemented in the MyStackArray class.
whenever I run the program I get Null exception error, I have tried to trace the cause till I found that the stack isn't filled with the initial data - maybe.
whenever I try to access stack or buffer I get the NullPointerException Error. and when I try to print the elements inside the array stack, I still get the silly NPE Error !!!

```
public class MyStackArray implements MyArrayI {
    private int[] buffer;
    private int[] stack;
    private int maxSize;

    public MyStackArray(int s){
        maxSize = s;
        int[] buffer = new int [maxSize];
        int[] stack = new int [maxSize];

        for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
            stack[i]=i;    // initiallizing the array with random values.
    }

    public void print(){              // tried to check the contents of the stack array.
         for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
          System.out.println(stack[i]); // causes Null Pointer Exception. ??!
        //System.out.println(stack[0]); // still causes the NPE !! 
    }

    public void setItemAt(int index, int item){
        int i;
        int j;

            for(i=0, j=maxSize-1 ; i<maxSize && j>=0 ; i++, j--){
                if(j == index)
                    break;
                buffer[i] = stack[j];  //causes a NULL.PointerException
           }
           stack[j] = item;   
    }

    public int getItemAt(int index){
        int i;
        int j;

            for(i=0, j=maxSize-1 ; i<maxSize && j>=0; i++, j--){
                if(j==index)
                    break;
                buffer[i] = stack[j];   // causes NPE
           }
           return stack[j];  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      MyStackArray X = new MyStackArray(3);
      //X.setItemAt(0,4);  // causes NPE
      //X.getItemAt(1);    // causes NPE
    X.print();             // causes NPE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] stack = new int [maxSize];
```

Here, you are creating a new variable called `stack` - this is not the same as `this.stack`. You instead want:

```
stack = new int[maxSize];  // i.e. initialize this.stack, not another variable
```

When left uninitialized, `this.stack` remains `null` and you receive an NPE when you try to access it.

P.S. You're also doing the same thing with `buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't properly initializing your variables:

```
public MyStackArray(int s){
    maxSize = s;
    int[] buffer = new int [maxSize]; // Initializes LOCAL buffer
    int[] stack = new int [maxSize]; // Initializes LOCAL stack

    for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
        stack[i]=i;    // initiallizing the array with random values.
}
```

Change like this:

```
public MyStackArray(int s){
    maxSize = s;
    buffer = new int [maxSize];
    stack = new int [maxSize];

    for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
        stack[i]=i;    // initiallizing the array with random values.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually initializing new (local) arrays in your constructors. you have

```
public MyStackArray(int s){
    maxSize = s;
    int[] buffer = new int [maxSize];  //You are declaring new array
    int[] stack = new int [maxSize];  //You are declaring new array

    for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
        stack[i]=i;    // initiallizing the array with random values.
}
```

But you should instead have this in your constructor:

```
public MyStackArray(int s){
    maxSize = s;
    buffer = new int [maxSize];
    stack = new int [maxSize];

    for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
        stack[i]=i;    // initiallizing the array with random values.
}
```